# Get Parent web of a subsite using JSOM in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, jsom

How can we get an immediate parent web of a subsite using JSOM ?

Comment: I am assuming you mean CSOM (Client Side Object Model).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using your SP.Web object, you can get the parent information (SP.WebInformation). Using its ID, you can then, via the site collection, get the parent web object.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();        
var web = context.get_web();                       
var parentInfo = web.get_parentWeb();  
var parentWeb = context.get_site().openWebById(parentInfo.get_id());

context.load(parentInfo);
context.load(parentWeb);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onListDataSucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed)); 

function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args)
{
    alert(this.parentWeb.get_title());
}

function onListDataFailed(sender, args)
{
    alert('error');
}
```

Methods used:

- [SP.Web.ParentWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246539.aspx)
- [SP.WebInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244790.aspx)
- [SP.Site.openWebById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247175.aspx)
- I also like [using this](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/sharepoint--SharePoint/) to navigate (faster than MS) within the JSOM API.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: the `WebInformation` object returned from `get_parentWeb` is also useful in many ways if you don't need to do further manipulation to the web object; it gives you access to the parent web title, server relative url, id, etc.

Comment: And also - I would add another plus 1 for the link to the definitely typed API reference, I didn't know about that version and it's much nicer than the MSDN reference

Comment: Shouldn't you execute the query to get the id from the parentWeb before you use it, so one will need two calls. Other than that it looks good :)

Comment: Anything for SharePoint 2010? Alternative to get_parentWeb()?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using the `get_parentWeb` is using the `_spPageContextInfo` object for urls and only needs one execute:

```
if(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl != _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl) {

  var parentWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/");
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(parentWebUrl);
  var web = ctx.get_web();
  ctx.load(web, "Title");
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    console.log(web.get_title());
  }, function(sender, args) {
    console.log("Err: " + args.get_message());
  }) 
}
```

Works in Office 365, tbh I'm not updated on the _spPageContextInfo object on prem, and what is available on it these days.

Answer (score 5):

Using REST API, it is very much easier to get parent web information. Just make a GET request to the following URL.

```
_api/Web/ParentWeb
```

In response, you will get all information about parent as like following.

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "http://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/ParentWeb",
      "uri": "http://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/ParentWeb",
      "type": "SP.WebInformation"
    },
    "Configuration": 0,
    "Created": "2016-01-04T10:59:47",
    "Description": "Parent site description",
    "Id": "495add3e-4b0c-485c-941b-d28130ef18c8",
    "Language": 1033,
    "LastItemModifiedDate": "2016-03-31T13:13:50Z",
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/parentSite",
    "Title": "Parent Site Title",
    "WebTemplate": "STS",
    "WebTemplateId": 0
  }
}
```

## Example Using pure JavaScript

```
function getParentWeb() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/Web/ParentWeb');

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var parentWeb = response.d;
                console.log(parentWeb); // parent web is here.


            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText)
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

## Example using jQuery

```
function getParentWeb() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/Web/ParentWeb',
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var parentWeb = response.d;
            console.log(parentWeb); // parent web is here.
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl property to get the url of the root web in the site collection.